# Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: magento2

i am currently searching to fix the problem.
After updating from Magento 2.3.5-p2 to 2.4 we get the following error message:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to serialize value. Error: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
<pre>#1 Magento\ReCaptchaCustomer\Plugin\Block\Account\InjectRecaptchaInAuthenticationPopup->afterGetJsLayout(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '{"components":{"...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:146]
#2 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#3 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getJsLayout', array(), array(array('inject_recaptcha...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Account/AuthenticationPopup/Interceptor.php:26]
#4 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->getJsLayout() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/authentication-popup.phtml:17]
#5 include('/var/www/share/m...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:71]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array('csp' => &Magento\Csp\Api\InlineUtilInterface\Proxy#00000000189bee30000000001cfdb34f#, 'secureRenderer' => &Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer\Proxy#00000000189beba4000000001cfdb34f#, 'escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper\Interceptor#00000000189bedc6000000001cfdb34f#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent('render', array(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array('escaper' => &Magento\Framework\Escaper\Interceptor#00000000189bedc6000000001cfdb34f#))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array()) called at [app/code/Amasty/Fpc/Plugin/Holepunch/TemplateRenderer.php:58]
#9 Amasty\Fpc\Plugin\Holepunch\TemplateRenderer->aroundRender(&Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor#00000000189be0de000000001cfdb34f#, &Closure#00000000189be1fa000000001cfdb34f#, &Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins('render', array(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array()), array(array('Amasty_Base::Add...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:26]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render(&Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor#00000000189bf373000000001cfdb34f#, '/var/www/share/m...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:273]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/share/m...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Account/AuthenticationPopup/Interceptor.php:180]
#14 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->fetchView('/var/www/share/m...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:303]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1111]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1115]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:675]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#19 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->___callParent('toHtml', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#20 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#21 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->___callPlugins('toHtml', array(), array(array('inject_plugin'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Customer/Block/Account/AuthenticationPopup/Interceptor.php:481]
#22 Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthenticationPopup\Interceptor->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:566]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('authentication-p...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:542]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('authentication-p...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('authentication-p...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('authentication-p...', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('authentication-p...', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('columns') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('columns', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.content') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.content', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#49 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#50 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#51 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#52 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:594]
#53 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:544]
#54 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#55 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:497]
#56 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#57 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:963]
#58 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#59 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent('getOutput', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#60 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#61 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#62 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#63 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#64 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#65 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#66 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [app/code/Amasty/GdprCookie/Plugin/ProcessPageResult.php:57]
#67 Amasty\GdprCookie\Plugin\ProcessPageResult->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#00000000189be1ca000000001cfdb34f#, &Closure#00000000189bed39000000001cfdb34f#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#68 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [app/code/Amasty/PageSpeedOptimizer/Plugin/ProcessPageResult.php:40]
#69 Amasty\PageSpeedOptimizer\Plugin\ProcessPageResult->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#00000000189be1ca000000001cfdb34f#, &Closure#00000000189bed39000000001cfdb34f#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#70 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [app/code/Magezon/Core/Plugin/View/Result/Layout.php:24]
#71 Magezon\Core\Plugin\View\Result\Layout->aroundRenderResult(&Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor#00000000189be1ca000000001cfdb34f#, &Closure#00000000189bed39000000001cfdb34f#, &Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#72 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#73 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#74 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be84b000000001cfdb34f#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#75 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#76 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:263]
#77 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000189be810000000001cfdb34f#) called at [index.php:39]
</pre>
```

Anyone a solution approach?

Answer (score 7):

The previous version of reCaptcha, msp/recaptcha, stored the keys in plain text. It appears that the migration to the replacement magento modules copies the keys to the new core_config_data paths. However these are configured to be encrypted. So, when 2.4.x loads these values and decrypts them, the result is the malformed UTF-8 in your error.

Deleting and re-saving the keys (for all stores) should resolve the problem

Comment: Legend! That did it. Too many people encouraging others to edit core vendor files as a solution to this problem.

Comment: The issue is referenced here - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/30486